# UINavigationItem does not work correctly - UINavigationBar does not look like should

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7

I try to add UINavigationBar to my UIView. When I add just UINavigationBar everything is OK. Problem occurs when I define UINavigationItem with title and two buttons and add this to my UINavigationBar. Check my code.

```
UINavigationBar *navigationBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc]init];
    [navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold" size:(20.0)];
    NSDictionary *attrNormal = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, font, NSFontAttributeName, nil];
    [navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:attrNormal];

    UINavigationItem *navigationItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Title"];


    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:primaryViewController action:nil];
    UIBarButtonItem *editButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit target:self action:@selector(tableEdit)];

    [navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:addButton animated:YES];
    [navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:editButton animated:YES];

    [self.navigationBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:navigationItem] animated:YES];

    [navigationBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, 60)];
    [self addSubview:navigationBar];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something wrong is going on when you are using "init" method.
If you change to initWithFrame everything is ok:

```
UINavigationBar *navigationBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 60)];
```

Comment: My above code is right. I found problem when I "init" custom UIView (parent of UINavigationBar). I used "self.bounds.size.width" for width of NavigationBar, so here is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you aren't using the `navigationItem` property of your VC? You wouldn't have to explicitly make a new UINavigationItem, you could simply add your bar button items by doing this:

```
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:YourButton];
```

Comment: Of course it is. I want to create only UIView with UINavigationBar.